# How do I link two Maven goals to execute before another?

Tags: maven

We want to use `mvn release:prepare` to release our build. However, we also build a dependency and both builds use SNAPSHOTs.

The Maven-versions-plugin can help us deal with this, so our build process would be:

```
mvn versions:update-properties
mvn versions:update-parent
svn ci
mvn release:prepare
```

I looked into how we could link these together and the simplest way I found was to write a plugin with a custom lifecycle: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html

Please can anyone do better? At that level of complexity, I'd rather just document the three lines.

The POMs would be very lengthy, hope this helps:

```
Parent (has a version)
|- ParentFather
|- ParentMother

Main (parent is Parent, has a version, contains property Child.version)
|- MainBrother (depends on MainSon and ParentFather)
|- MainSister
|- MainDaughter (has version Child.version)
|- MainSon (has version Child.version)
```

So to release Main, which is my end-goal, I need to release Parent, Son, and Daughter. Having done that, I need to update Main to use these versions.

Comment: Can give an excerpt of the pom's you are using for this project ? mvn version:update-parent seems to be a little bit strange to me...Usually in a multi-module build a mvn release:prepare release:perform is enough...

Comment: @khmarbaise, you may be right that m-release-p would do the update-parent for us, but I don't think it would manage to update the Child.version property. If it does, that would solve the problem!

Comment: Is Main on the same level as Parent ? If Yes so you need to release Parent structure first and afterwars you can releae Main simply by using mvn release cycle (may be you need to update your parent in Main). But based on your description it sounds like the Main must be a sub-level under Parent correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate it, a simple script could also help. You could even add some evaluation of the return value to make sure that the previous step didn't fail.

Have you looked into using a profile to execute the steps in that order? You could bind the `versions` plugin steps to an early phase of the project, and then follow with the SVN commit (use the SCM plugin) and the release.

Comment: A script is an option, but it would affect build portability and there's the temptation to slip in "just one more command". A profile might be possible, it feels a bit hacky but I'll look into it.